# What should the ticket-to-ride tag represent?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should [ticket-to-ride](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride) represent:

- Questions specifically about the original US version of the game (e.g. [What is the maximum score in Ticket to Ride USA, and how to aim towards it?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/what-is-the-maximum-score-in-ticket-to-ride-usa-and-how-to-aim-towards-it))
- Questions about the family of games in general (e.g. [How Unethical Is A Purely "Blocking" Move In Ticket To Ride?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/how-unethical-is-a-purely-blocking-move-in-ticket-to-ride))
- Something else

and if either of the first two options, how should questions about the other option be tagged?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have no strong views on this other than thinking it would be useful to separate the two concepts.

Answer (score 4):

It is best for a single tag to not be used to represent multiple separate concepts, so this tag should be divided:

- [ticket-to-ride-series](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride-series) for questions that apply to the family of games in general (the simple [ticket-to-ride](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride) tag would still be ambiguous).
- [ticket-to-ride-usa](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride-usa) for questions about the USA version of the game in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The guidance for the tag shows it as referring to the series:

> The original game is set in North America. Several alternatives with different maps and some extra rules also exist:

I can see a few issues here. First I believe the question was asked correctly and Philip was asking for clarification that had been given, the questioner specified the full name of one of the games in the series, which happened to be part of the name of all other games, and in my opinion this is the correct way this should be handled.

Do we really want to explode tags? Ticket to Ride as a series has over a dozen versions now, will we have one tag for each? Do we do the same for Poker, have a `Texas hold 'em`, a `Caribbean Stud`, a `7 card stud` and more? A tag for each possible version of Dominion? I know that's a ridiculous extreme but it is kind of the direction separating series tags like this could go.

I see tags as meant to be the broad strokes categories, for many games that only fits one thing, for others that fits the series as a whole and the question content should narrow that down.

That being said, a tag can get big enough to deserve this kind of splitting, we have [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander) as an example separated out from [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) as a broad category, but there are nearly 5000 Magic the Gathering questions on this stack, there are a total of 120 for Ticket to Ride, I don't think it's anywhere near that point.

Comment: There is very little downside to having many tags, or to having tags with few questions. You cite, [tag:mtg-commander], the most populated [tag:magic-the-gathering] subtag, but there is also [tag:mtg-archenemy] with one question, and that's fine too.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I believe you misunderstood - I cited mtg-commander as one of the tags under the umbrella of magic-the-gathering, and that magic-the-gathering has so many sub-tags because the umbrella of mtg as a whole, not any specific sub-tag, has thousands of questions. mtg-commander has only 285 questions out of the 4995 total for magic-the-gathering currently. I feel because of that size Magic needs that 5k broken down, even if those sub-tags only have a few questions.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can represent many things.

- Questions about the base game
- Questions about the family of games
- Questions about expansions when used in conjunction with the expansion tag

Comment: This then leads to issues with questions like this https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/how-should-the-final-round-be-carried-out-in-ticket-to-ride (which is what prompted this meta question) where it is unclear whether the poster is asking about specifically about the original, an arbitrary unspecified entry in the series (perhaps because they are not aware of other versions) or asking whether this is something which applies across all/the majority of games in the series.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I don't see the issue with that question and it was answered just fine. If they are asking about a different version that has a different ending mechanic they should include that in the question.

Comment: One of the main purposes of a tag is to communicate exactly that kind of information in a question. If the tag is ambiguous, it doesn't serve that purpose effectively.