# Ticket to Ride Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Based on this question [What should the ticket-to-ride tag represent?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/what-should-the-ticket-to-ride-tag-represent) it seems we want to have a tag for each version of the game to make it clear what version of the game is discussed.

Based on that should a question that is about a version of ticket to ride also include the base ticket to ride tag? For example a question with the [ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom) that is about that version should it also have a [ticket-to-ride](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride) tag?

My opinion is that the [ticket-to-ride](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride) tag is unneeded for questions about a specific version and should only be used for questions about the entire family of games.